# problem understaning /.*/

Tags: regular-expression, ed

I have problem understanding `/.*/` according to things written in books, this prints the entire line of the text. we know that`.` means any character, and `*` means zero or more occurrence of the preceding character. so I expect that /.*/ finds something like `rrr` `qqqq` `abbbbb`, I mean continuously repetition of a single character.

but this is not the thing it does. ***why?***

*my second question is*: why `/.+/` doesn't do the same thing?? in the text I'm trying on the result is `?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `*` in `.*` means "any number of the preceding *expression*", i.e. zero or more of whatever type of character that matches the expression `.`.

This means that `.*` will match `aaaa` as well as `abcd` since all of the characters in `abcd` matches `.`.  It will also match an empty line, since it allows for *zero* matches.

If you'd like to find a line that contains a *repeated* character, use

```
/\(.\)\1\1*/
```

This expression matches "any character, then *the same character*, and then any number of more of the same character".  The `\1*` could arguably be removed unless you're looking for lines that contain *only* a repeated character, in which case you should anchor the expression to the start and end of the line, as in

```
/^\(.\)\1\1*$/
```

The `ed` editor supports *basic* regular expressions.  The `+` modifier is an *extended* regular expression modifier. The `?` that you get from `ed` when using `/.+/` would be followed by `no match` (or `No match` in GNU `ed`) if you had enabled error explanations with the `H` command. This is because it tries to find a line with a `+` in it, preceded by some other character.

The `.+` extended regular expression ("match one or more of any character") is equivalent to the basic regular expression `..*`, i.e. "match a character, and then zero or more of any character".

According to [its manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Regular-expressions), GNU `ed` should support `\+` in regular expressions, so that `..*` is equivalent to `.\+`, but GNU `ed` 1.14.2 on my OpenBSD system does not do this.

Comment: Even if the `*` referred to copies of the same character, it matches _zero or more_, so it would still match on any line since a zero amount of something is really easy to find...

Comment: Great work and congrats on the 100K!